# Json string to Datatable conversion

Tags: c#, json, datatable

I am having the following json string.

```
"data": {
  "message": "Ok",
  "success": true,
  "serverTime": 1550568846,
  "pageNo": 0,
  "pageSize": 100,
  "totalPages": 1,
  "totalCount": 7,
  "list": [
    {
      "vehicleNumber": "NL01N7848",
      "deviceNumber": "358735072950479",
      "vendorCode": "WE12881",
      "venndorName": "kapoor Diesels",
      "latitude": 12.195035555555556,
      "longitude": 76.642826666666664,
      "speed": 0.0,
      "createdDate": 1550497439,
      "location": "Unnamed Road, Byathahalli, Karnataka 571311, India",
      "provider": "WHEELSEYE",
      "vehicleType": "NA",
      "accurate": false
    },
    {
      "vehicleNumber": "NL01L0067",
      "deviceNumber": "358735073314899",
      "vendorCode": "WE12881",
      "venndorName": "kapoor Diesels",
      "latitude": 26.222473333333333,
      "longitude": 91.702311111111115,
      "speed": 0.0,
      "createdDate": 1550568823,
      "location": "21, Brahmaputra Industrial Park, Gauripur, Amingaon, Guwahati - Baihata Rd, Guwahati, Assam 781030, India",
      "provider": "WHEELSEYE",
      "vehicleType": "NA",
      "ignition": false,
      "accurate": false
    },
    {
      "vehicleNumber": "NL01L1004",
      "deviceNumber": "358735073306135",
      "vendorCode": "WE12881",
      "venndorName": "kapoor Diesels",
      "latitude": 20.532204444444446,
      "longitude": 85.952977777777775,
      "speed": 0.0,
      "createdDate": 1550568795,
      "location": "Badshahi Road, Alarpur, Odisha 754025, India",
      "provider": "WHEELSEYE",
      "vehicleType": "NA",
      "ignition": true,
      "accurate": false
    },
    {
      "vehicleNumber": "NL01L2044",
      "deviceNumber": "358735073318866",
      "vendorCode": "WE12881",
      "venndorName": "kapoor Diesels",
      "latitude": 22.567486666666664,
      "longitude": 88.136897777777776,
      "speed": 0.0,
      "createdDate": 1550568787,
      "location": "Amta-Ranihati Road, Ranihati, Mallik Bagan, West Bengal 711302, India",
      "provider": "WHEELSEYE",
      "vehicleType": "NA",
      "ignition": false,
      "accurate": false
    },
    {
      "vehicleNumber": "NL01L2042",
      "deviceNumber": "358735073311713",
      "vendorCode": "WE12881",
      "venndorName": "kapoor Diesels",
      "latitude": 20.532215555555556,
      "longitude": 85.953057777777772,
      "speed": 0.0,
      "createdDate": 1550568825,
      "location": "Badshahi Road, Alarpur, Odisha 754025, India",
      "provider": "WHEELSEYE",
      "vehicleType": "NA",
      "ignition": false,
      "accurate": false
    },
    {
      "vehicleNumber": "NL01L6027",
      "deviceNumber": "NA",
      "vendorCode": "WE12881",
      "venndorName": "kapoor Diesels",
      "latitude": 13.265313,
      "longitude": 80.11657,
      "speed": 0.0,
      "createdDate": 1550565467,
      "location": "Tirupati Rd, Manjankaranai, Tamil Nadu 601103, India",
      "provider": "WHEELSEYE",
      "vehicleType": "NA",
      "accurate": false
    },
    {
      "vehicleNumber": "HR38U3103",
      "deviceNumber": "NA",
      "vendorCode": "WE12881",
      "venndorName": "kapoor Diesels",
      "latitude": 27.594013,
      "longitude": 77.59916,
      "speed": 44.0,
      "createdDate": 1550568763,
      "location": "NH19, Bharthia, Uttar Pradesh 281406, India",
      "provider": "WHEELSEYE",
      "vehicleType": "NA",
      "ignition": true,
      "accurate": false
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to convert it to a C# class object.
I am using the following class structure:

```
class Data
    {
        JsonData data { get; set; }
    }
    class JsonData
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public Int64 serverTime { get; set; }
        public int pageNo { get; set; }
        public int pageSize { get; set; }
        public int totalPages { get; set; }
        public int totalCount { get; set; }
        List<VehicleDetails> list { get; set; }
    }
    class VehicleDetails
    {
        public string vehicleNumber { get; set; }
        public string deviceNumber { get; set; }
        public string vendorCode { get; set; }
        public string venndorName { get; set; }
        public double latitude { get; set; }
        public double longitude { get; set; }
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public Int64 createdDate { get; set; }
        public string location { get; set; }
        public string provider { get; set; }
        public string vehicleType { get; set; }
        public bool accurate { get; set; }
    }
```

But every time when I am trying to deserialize the above json, an exception is coming that says **Invalid array passed in**

**EDIT:**

Here is the code of deserialization:

```
string jsonString;
JavaScriptSerializer jSerObj = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Data> lstData = (List<Data>) jSerObj.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<Data>));
```

**EDIT-2:**

I have removed the outer [] from my json string

Please help me on this.

Comment: Where is your deserialization code?

Comment: your example `JSON` string in a `JSON-Array` and not an `JSON-object` as it starts with `[` and ends with `]`. So, if your code uses something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(<your json string here>);` change it to something like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(<your json string here>);`.

Comment: Your Json is not in valid format. It would be better you begin by examining and correcting your json

Comment: Upload it to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and you will get an error `Error:Expecting comma or ], not colon.`, or https://jsonlint.com/ which reports `Error: Parse error on line 1: Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'`  The basic problem is that the outer container delimiter is `[` indicating an array, but `"data": {}` is an object property.

Comment: @er-sho I have added the code that I am using for deserialization

Comment: @dbc.. I can get rid of outer [] brackets

Comment: @DeepakVerma, and what about datatable in your question. Which data in json you want to be parse it to DataTable?

Comment: @er-sho... only the "list" part.... not specifically into datatable object ... either the specialized object or datatable object will serve the purpose

Comment: @DeepakVerma, So now which is your json? means its with `[]` or you remove those brackets. so which one I considered to give you solution?

Comment: @DeepakVerma, edit your question and provide final json that you want to parsed. so we can help you

Comment: @er-sho... I have edited the json string in my question

Comment: @DeepakVerma, I added my answer below try it and let me know

Comment: @DeepakVerma, Did you tried my answer. I updated now.

Comment: yes.. it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I considered as this is your json,

```
{
  "data": {
    "message": "Ok",
    "success": true,
    "serverTime": 1550568846,
    "pageNo": 0,
    "pageSize": 100,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalCount": 7,
    "list": [
      {
        "vehicleNumber": "NL01N7848",
        ...
      },
      {
        "vehicleNumber": "NL01L0067",
        ...
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you can deserailize this json as,

```
Data lstData = (Data)jSerObj.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(Data));
```

After doing above stuff you still get `list` as null

So add access modifier `public` to property `list` in your `JsonData` class and `data` property in `Data` class, So after applying public access modifier

```
class Data
{
    public JsonData data { get; set; }
}

class JsonData
{
    ...
    public List<VehicleDetails> list { get; set; }
}
```

---

**Alternative:**

From your json, If you want to parse your `list` key data directly to `DataTable` then you can use below code

```
string json = File.ReadAllText(@"Path to your json file");

JToken jToken = JToken.Parse(json);

DataTable dataTable = jToken["data"]["list"].ToObject<DataTable>();
```

**Note:** You need to install `newtonsoft.json` package from Nuget Package Manager. And then you need to import `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;` namespace to your program

**Output:** You output data table look like

[image]

Comment: worked like a charm... I used your alternative solution

Comment: Yes I think so, you want parse  list to direct datatable that's why I'd provide you an alternative, glad to hear and welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is invalid. It starts and ends with `[` & `]` which implies an array. Array elements do not have key/value pairs. Just elements.

Either

1. Replace the start and end with `{` and `}`. or;
2. Remove the `data` key at the start and just have an array of `JsonData`

If you choose 1. above, your parsing code should become

```
Data lstData = (Data) jSerObj.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(Data));
```

and if you chose 2. it should be:

```
List<JsonData> lstData = (List<JsonData>) jSerObj.Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(List<JsonData>));
```

---

After your edit:

Your data is still not valid - now it has nothing around it. You can parse it using option 1. above by appending `{` and `}` around what you have there.

---

Edit 2

You should use [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for deserialization - it is far superior to `JsonSerializer`

Code is:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(jsonString);
```

Live example: https://rextester.com/WRXSO2016

(Note you were also missing a couple of `public` access modifiers in your classes)

Comment: I tried the 1st solution as given by you.. it is giving data as null

Comment: I tried exactly what is given in 1st solution... still the data is null

Comment: @DeepakVerma see Edit 2.

Comment: it worked ... thanks a lot mate... however I applied the solution as given above